# Will the jquery POST work if triggered but don't get enough time to execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, async-await

let's say the `backend_page_to_update_db.php` page take around 5 secs to update the data into DB.

**Question #1 :**

```
$(".update_btn").on("click",() => {
 $.post('backend_page_to_update_db.php',
   {
     value1 : value1,
     value2 : value2
   }, function(result) {
        $(".some_class").text("done with updating database");
   });
});
```

My question is, upon clicking on the `update_btn` button I closed the page with in 2 secs or so.
Will the DB gets updated with `POST` data since the page is triggered or will it get cancelled as well.

Presuming it gets updated in DB irrespective we wait for it or not, Please check the same for the below code as well.

**Quesiton #2 :**

```
$(".update_btn").on("click",() => {
  
  var main = async () => {

  var fun2 = (value) => {
    new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      value = value + 1;
      
      $.post('backend_page_to_update_db_2.php',
       {
         value : value,
       }, function(result) {
            console.log("fun2 done");
       });

      return resolve(fun1(value));
    });
  };

  var fun3 = () => {
    new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      value = 1;
      $.post('backend_page_to_update_db_3.php',
       {
         value : value,
       }, function(result) {
            console.log("fun3 done");
       });

      return resolve(fun2(value));
    });
  };

  var fun1 = (value) => {
    new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      value = value + 1;
      
      $.post('backend_page_to_update_db_1.php',
       {
         value : value,
       }, function(result) {
            console.log("fun1 done");
       });

      return resolve(value);
    });
  };

  fun3();
  };

main();

});
```

1. Presuming I closed the window after i see the **fun3** and **fun2** get executed through console, and closed the window.
   i.e., The **fun1** query got triggered and the window wasn't opened till it gets executed.
   Will the **fun1** query get executed..?
2. Presuming I closed the window after i see the **fun3** alone in the console and closed the window,
   i.e., The **fun2** might got triggered but the **fun1** wasn't, which can cause issues with data in DB, In these kinda scenarios we need to delete the recent updates or insert that happened recently using reject or failure in the promise. But How..?

Note: Edits to this query are welcomed.

Comment: I would generally expect that you can't *reliably assume* the operations completed under such circumstances.  If the end user wants to know it was done, they should wait until it's done.  In the event that this takes a long time and the user loses patience, the performance of the operation should be addressed rather than chasing this rabbit of how reliable the browser may or may not be.

Comment: If the database operations are completed and response is yet to be sent to user it will persist in DB. Once request is initiated it start the code execution

Comment: *"The fun2 might got triggered but the fun1 wasn't, which can cause issues with data in DB"* - Then the operation should be re-designed to handle or prevent such "issues".  It's never a good idea to rely on the client to maintain data integrity for you.

Comment: @David Nah, I get it, thats why I thought of passing the recent edited or inserted row id to the next function's reject as well, just incase if the user decides to terminate the process inbetween, so that the reject will have to handle on reverting the recent changes to keep the DB clean. I was just wondering, if is this the only way or is there anything else to learn on this.?

Comment: By the structure of your promises, I would say: fun3 gets called, then fun3 executes the $.post, and calls fun2, then fun2 calls $.post and calls fun1, which in turn calls $.post and return the reference to value. Each call should happen almost immediately, without waiting for the $.post calls to finish. So everything is executed.

Comment: @TechStackbyAntra: That sounds like an overly-complicated approach which, in an effort to no longer rely on the client, still relies on the client to maintain that effort.  Take a step back from your proposed solution(s) and focus on the actual business problem.  What is it you're trying to accomplish?  Is the problem that you have a long-running process and the user isn't waiting for the result?  Is the problem that you have a multi-step process and the user is canceling it part-way through?  Something else?  The solution may have nothing to do with browsers or promises.

Comment: As it is a fixed number of steps, I would do it on the backend on one $.post, that way I can be sure of what is executed, and the steps to follow in case something fails and needs undoing.

Comment: See the Promise reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)